# Vectorizing disparityMap in Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, vectorization, matlab-cvst

I am implementing an Sum of Square Distances based disparity Map function in Matlab for computer vision. Currently the code has a nested for loop and runs very slow. Any suggestions on vectorizing it to make it more efficient? Thanks

```
%im1 and im2 are images and win1, win2 are window sizes
for i=win1+1:1:bottom-win1
    parfor j=win2+1:1:right-win2
        %j=[win2+1:bottom-win2];
        template=im1(i-win1:i+win1,j-win2:j+win2);
        arg1=conv2(im2.^2,ones(size(template))/2,'same');
        arg2=conv2(im2,rot90(template,2),'same');
        arg=arg1-arg2;
        [xj]=find(arg==min(arg(:)));

        disparityMap(i,j)=1-xj(1);


    end
end
```

Comment: I do not see how this can be easily vectorized, but there are some obvious improvements: `arg1` does not depend on `i` and `j`, so it is constant, so [move it out of the loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)! I guess you can also rotate the complete `im1` only once before the loop, if you adjust the indices for extracting the template a bit.

Comment: You can also use the `disparity` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three suggestions to try to speed things up:

- move the parfor to the outer loop to reduce the overhead of the parallel construct ;
- compute `im2.^2` once before the loop and save its  value in a temporary variable as it does not depend on the loop variables there is no need to compute it again and again, and actually
- move the whole computation of `arg1` out of the loops as it only depends on the size of `template` and not its value, and if I see correctly, the size is constant ;
- replace the `[xj]=find(arg==min(arg(:)));` construct with something along the lines of `[tmp, ind] = min(arg(:)) ; xj=ind2sub(size(arg), ind)` to avoid the call to `find` and rescan the matrix while the indices can be computed simply.

Untested, but it should give you a start

```
arg1=conv2(im2.^2,ones([2*win1+1, 2*win2+1])/2,'same');
parfor i=win1+1:1:bottom-win1
    for j=win2+1:1:right-win2
        %j=[win2+1:bottom-win2];
        template=im1(i-win1:i+win1,j-win2:j+win2);
        arg2=conv2(im2,rot90(template,2),'same');
        arg=arg1-arg2;
        [tmp, ind] = min(arg(:)) ; 
        xj=ind2sub(size(arg), ind);

        disparityMap(i,j)=1-xj(1);

    end
end
```

Also make sure the number of workers is chosen appropriately, and try to compile the code to mex to see if there is improvement.